# Hosts entry getting ignored when in vpn

Tags: mac, vpn, dns, proxy, hosts-file

I am using Mac and I added entry for myname.local in hosts file. But when I try to reach myname.local:8000 my browser is directly going to dns. I have verified that I have entry in bypass proxy for *.local

- when I am not in vpn it works as expected and picks up 127.0.0.1 for myname.local
- even when I am in vpn curl myname.local:8000 gives me correct result

What should I do so that chrome or any other browser resolves the name based on hosts entry?

Comment: So what happens if you try to go to `127.0.0.1:8000` when connected to the VPN. It sounds like the VPN does not allow split tunneling.

Comment: I get dns error, like the name can not be resolved. I was thinking, since localhost works and properly resolves to 127.0.0.1 there must be some file browser is reading before it goes to proxy.

Comment: Jarus - Whose VPN or you connected to? Have you talked with the Network or VPN Administrators that maintain the tunnel definitions to ask them about this? You may find the quick accurate answer by simply asking those that  maintain the VPN server or router you are connecting to. Sometimes when you are connected to a VPN via IPSEC, you are just locked down for compliance and security reasons. There may be a client hack around this issue but to resolve in the meantime, simply disconnect from the VPN to access the network resource. Use a virtual machine for your VPN client connection too.

Comment: Explain how you connect to this VPN exactly when you get a chance as well.